# Show and Hide tables with Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm currently designing a price table. The table will have three options:

- Personal
- Professional
- Business

each of these options will be on a button. The idea is that when the user clicks on the corresponding button, the table of that plan will be shown.

**How should this be done with bootstrap? using jquery?**

My logic tells me that it should be something like having all 3 tables in the html and modifying the `display` attribute according to the button that is clicked. However, I am not entirely clear on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap has an [inbuilt collapse function](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/) for this, or you could look into its [tab functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior) depending on what you're looking for.

Of course this is also entirely possible to make from scratch in jQuery, but since you seem to be mainly looking for a Bootstrap solution, one of these might be it for you. It might be a time-saver for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

you'll probably have to use JQuery indeed. You'll have the choice play with 
hide() or show(), but, instead, I prefer to do it like this :

```
$("#personal_table_btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#personal_table").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Bootstrap got a nice "hidden" class you can toggle, which is very convenient.

Concerning the html, well, you don't really want to load three racks of data when you just need one, so maybe do an ajax call to get only the one you need and display it ?

Comment: Fyi, you obviously don’t need jq for that. Have a look at querySelector and classList

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll check that.